# Error in using gammu in php exec

Tags: php, ubuntu, gammu

I successfully installed gammu in ubuntu 11, and send text message using command line.
`echo "TEXTMESSAGE"` | gammu sendsms TEXT *mobilenumber*

My problem is, when I use exec function in my php script I always have the following errors:

```
Warning: No configuration file found!
Warning: No configuration read, using builtin defaults!
Error opening device, it doesn't exist.
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: found a couple of php\gammu classes via google

Comment: Thank you for fast reply Dagon, is it ok for you to give me a link?

Comment: https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=gammu+php the first 3 look promising

Comment: Thanks Dagon, but still, no luck... its the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the .gammurc and the defaults fail to detect your device. 
Try running gammu-detect. It should say something along the lines of

```
[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = Phone on USB serial port HUAWEI_Technology HUAWEI_Mobile
connection = at
```

If that does not work, run gammu-config and manually set up port and connection.

Comment: thanks you for the reply @rjs, I already did the settings succesfully, the only problem is, when I try using the exec function for php

<?php
exec ('echo "TEXTMESSAGE" | gammu sendsms TEXT mobilenumber');
?>

it wont work, it looks like apache dont have permission to execute gammu.

Comment: I should read more carefully, you actually said you could send messages with the command line therefore not the config. What user does the php script run as? Is that user a member of the dialout group?

Comment: I am sorry @rjs but I am not a good or not even close being a system administrator, I am actually having a hard time looking for what user group it run. I am sorry again, I've actually read some http-user but still it doesnt work - I already added then to the dial-out group - thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Just resolved the similar trouble. In my case gammu was executed under nagios user, so that it was not able to find the configuration file until I placed it in /etc/gammurc.
According to [gammu documentation](http://wammu.eu/docs/manual/config/index.html?highlight=gammurc#synopsis) on Linux, MacOS X, BSD and other Unix-like systems, the config file is searched in following order:

1. $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/gammu/config
2. ~/.config/gammu/config
3. ~/.gammurc
4. /etc/gammurc

My file was in /home/user/.gammurc, but when I executed it under nagios user "~" was a different directory, so that gammu was not able to find it.

Now permissions:
In order to gain access for your user to `/dev/ttyUSB0` (use your path) you should add `nagios` (in your case `www-data` or whatever it is) user to `dialout` group this way:

```
sudo usermod -a -G dialout nagios
```

And then set the SUID bit on `gammu` to allow `nagios` (`www-data` in your case) execute it on behalf of the root:

```
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/gammu
```

Try to execute `gammu` on behalf of the root (you could use `su` command)
Hope it would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can change de path of .gammurc by doing this:

Copy the file (.gammurc) located on the root and past it on /etc.

cp .gammurc /etc/gammurc

Don't forget to remove the dot.
I use it raspberry Pi , the directory of gammu may change on your environment